# Propagating a Tiles attribute down the include chain

Tags: jsp, tiles2

I'm using Tiles and I'd like an attribute defined for a page to be readable inside of one of the included subpages as follows:

`tiles-definitions.xml`:

```
<definition name="page" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/layout/page.jsp">
  <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/_include/header.jsp"/>
  <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/_include/footer.jsp"/>
</definition>

<definition name="tutorial" extends="page">
  <put-attribute name="title" value="Tutorial"/>
  <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/tutorial.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

The `page.jsp` represents a simple page structure:

```
<html>
  <head><title><tiles:getAsString name="title"/></title></head>
  <body>
      <tiles:insertAttribute name="header"/>
      <tiles:insertAttribute name="body"/>
      <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to read the title also inside the "header" subpage but I get the following error:

> org.apache.tiles.template.NoSuchAttributeException: Attribute 'title' not found.

Here is how I'm trying to access the attribute in header.jsp:

```
<tiles:getAsString name="title"/>
```

Answer (score 22):

To propagate the `title` attribute to inner templates you need to add `cascade="true"` attribute to the `title`'s `<put-attribute>` tag, like this:

```
<definition name="tutorial" extends="page">
  <put-attribute name="title" cascade="true" value="Tutorial"/>
  <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/tutorial.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

Comment: It worked for me as well. It's been awhile -- stack-o-frankie, can you accept this answer?

Comment: In addition if you use `<tiles:importAttribute/>` instead of `<tiles:getAsString/>` then you can use the attribute in EL with `${attribute}`

Answer (score 5):

Take care to upgrade the Tiles definition file to 2.1 min, as cascade is available since 2.1.

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">
```