# How do I extend templates in tiles?

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, tiles

I have one master template that has the general site layout frame: "/WEB-INF/jsp/common.jsp"
Then I have another template that will be generally used for another number of pages with similar layout: "/WEB-INF/jsp/features/common.jsp"

The features template basically defines the content of attribute "content" of the "master" template.

I have tried to solve this the following way:

```
<definition name="product.common" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/common.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/features/common.jsp" />
</definition>
<definition name="features/index" extends="product.common">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Features" />
    <put-attribute name="rightContent" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/features/index.jsp" />
</definition>
```

But this does not work. I get the following error message in my stack trace:

> org.apache.tiles.template.NoSuchAttributeException: Attribute 'rightContent' not found.

But the features-template does have the following:

```
<tiles:insertAttribute name="rightContent" />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you need is [nesting definitions](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tutorial/advanced/nesting-extending.html).  You could try something like this.

```
<definition name="features.common" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/features/common.jsp">
</definition>

<definition name="product.common" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/common.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="features.common" />
</definition>

<definition name="features/index" extends="product.common">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Features" />
    <put-attribute name="rightContent" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/features/index.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Comment: How is that different from mine?

Comment: @Piotr. If you look carefully, in my example, content holds a *subdefinition* value

Comment: Ok, I tried that and got "org.apache.tiles.template.NoSuchAttributeException: Attribute 'rightContent' not found.
". The problem is that "rightContent" is in the feature-common template. Any other ideas?

Comment: The solution was to use cascading! :) Thanks for your help tho

Comment: @Piotr. It'd be better if you add your answer to your question (even better if you point to an existing answer: [Propagating a Tiles attribute down the include chain](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4757812/413020)). The accepted answer, as you state, does not point into the right direction.